# Requesting domain on a custom port doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I have route53 configured to work with my domain and ec2 with apache and nodejs.

I have apache on the port 80 and nodejs app running on the port 3000.

Requests to the IP:80 and to the domain.com:80 work OK - apache responses correctly.

Requesting IP:3000 **works OK** (nodejs receives requests), but to the domain.com:3000 **it doesn't work** - node.js doesn't receive any requests at all.

Connecting via SSH to IP:22 and domain.com:22 works well too.

What is happening with requests to the domain.com:3000? How can I fix that?

Comment: have you added a `virtual host` entry for `domain.com:3000` to your apache config

Comment: @iamcaleberic I have only one vhost listening on port 80. Even if my non-apache app is on the port 3000 I need to set up an additional apache vhost on the port 3000? If yes - how to redirect it to nodejs:3000?

Comment: To access it on port 3000 add a virtual host entry like the one for port 80 with your domain.

Comment: @iamcaleberic but I want apache to listen port 80 only, my nodejs is listening on port 3000.

Comment: you can set up apache as a `reverse proxy to port 3000` or change your node js app to run on `port 80.`

Comment: check this on how to reverse proxy with apache - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I'd say your problem is most likely with node.js not recognizing domain.com as a web site it manages and then dropping a connection. Try setting up something else listening on port 3000 instead (e.g. apache) and see what's happening. I'm pretty sure apache will work with domain.com:3000 too. But in any case, at least you'll have the issue narrowed down.